GitHub Actions for executing remote ssh
ssh username@hostIP works in Ubuntu.
but I got error when I execute remote ssh on Github actions.
-workflows file
name: 'build-and-deploy'
on: 
  push:
    branches:
      - hanul

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3.3.0

      - name: execute remote ssh
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@v0.1.3
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
          port: ${{ secrets.SSH_PORT }}
          script: |
            whoami
            


result

dial tcp :: i/o timeout
*I set the ports to the same as in the sshd_config

Not a lot of detail here on the problem itself, but: are you sure GitHub is permitted to SSH to the Ubuntu system?

@JimRedmond I'm trying this. https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action

Is the host IP in one of these ranges? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_addresses

@JimRedmond I checked and I was using a private IP. now I'm testing locally with a public IP, and when I do ssh -p [port] [username]@[public IP], I'm getting a connection timeout. I've checked my firewall, I've checked the port settings on sshd.

Up until this point, I had only modified the sshd_config file on ubuntu. I modified the sshd_config file on Windows, and the connection works.
I can connect, but it keeps asking for a password. When I enter the password, it says “permission denied”. The authentication key doesn't work. when I tried on Github actions, error is "ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain"

You really, really, really need to provide these details up front.

It seems you cannot access from the GitHub Actions. Do you ensure you allow access on the firewall or something like that?

I checked firewall is inactive.I also set something like PermitRootLogin=yes just in case
